# My namespace has a name same as .net framework namespace

Tags: c#, .net

I get this problem but don't know how to fix it. I don't like to change namespace. This is my code:

```
namespace ParlayRMS.Models.System
{
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;

    public class MaintenanceInfo
    {
        public MaintenanceInfo()
        {
            IsDownTime = false;
            TimeFrom = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            TimeTo = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        public bool IsDownTime { get; set; }
        public string TimeFrom { get; set; }
        public string TimeTo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This class causes error: "Type or namespace 'DateTime' could not be found." because this class is put in namespace System which same as with .NET Framework. If I change "ParlayRMS.Models.System" to "ParlayRMS.Models", this class will be ok but I don't like this way. I need a solution for this case without changing many codes.

THanks.

Comment: Why must you use the name `System` in your namespace?

Comment: Because I must follow styleCop rules

Comment: StyleCop is not a standard, it is only a good tool. Feel free to alter its configurations - as long as you consistent with your team members

Comment: StyleCop never says you should name your namespace `System`. It just says usings should be placed inside your namespace, but I don't care about that - I'm asking why you need to name your namespace `System` at all. Why can't you change it?

Comment: So basically you have a combination of a silly rule, and a silly naming pattern that blows up in your face. It's always fun when things combine in unexpected ways :D

Comment: @BoltClock: I use the name "System" because of the meaning (function) of the class MaintenanceInfo. I should put it in namespace System of my project (not in .NET Framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `System` in `using System.Globalization` is referring to you namespace, so it should be another compile error there.

If you really like the `using`s within the namespace (a practice that I, personally, dislike), you should use the `global::` extern alias (I think that's what it's called)

```
namespace ParlayRMS.Models.System
{
    using global::System;
    using global::System.Globalization;

    public class MaintenanceInfo
    {
        public MaintenanceInfo()
        {
            IsDownTime = false;
            TimeFrom = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            TimeTo = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        public bool IsDownTime { get; set; }
        public string TimeFrom { get; set; }
        public string TimeTo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the usings outside:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ParlayRMS.Models.System
{

    public class MaintenanceInfo
    {
        public MaintenanceInfo()
        {
            IsDownTime = false;
            TimeFrom = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            TimeTo = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        public bool IsDownTime { get; set; }
        public string TimeFrom { get; set; }
        public string TimeTo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: But It will fail StyleCop rule.

Comment: StyleCop requires you to put using statements inside the namespace blocks? If you put them in there, they're not even referring to the right namespaces.  They'll be referring to `ParlayRMS.Models.System.System` and `ParlayRMS.Models.System.System.Globalization`

Comment: Actually (according to VS 2012) they refer to `ParlayRMS.Models.System` and `ParlayRMS.Models.System.Globalization`. And @Lulu, do you really, really have to obey that StyleCop rule?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have using statements inside the namespace block?  If you move them outside, I believe it should build just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
global::System.DateTime dateTime;
```

or in another way:

```
using SystemAlias = System;
```

then:

```
SystemAlias.DateTime dateTime;
```

BTW: Put your usings before namespace declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
using NETDateTime = System.DateTime;
```

And then in your code:

```
TimeFrom = NETDateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Won't work, the `System` refers to the local, not the global `System` namespace.